# How can I add special classes to only all blocks that's generated in certain region?

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

I want to add some classes to each block that generated in custom region automatically.
For example I want to all blocks that generated within sidebar-left have some special classes and in addition I don't want to those blocks in other regions have those classes.

I try to use something like below code to add desired class to each block that's generated in sidebar-left:

**region--sidebar-left.html.twig**

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'region',
    'region-' ~ region,
  ]
%}
{% if content %}
  <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
    {{ content }}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

But it seems there isn't any loop functionality Like below to I can use for each blocks and add my desired classes to them:

```
{% for item in items %}
  <div class="my-desired-class">
    {{ content }}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to - you can target blocks in a region using the region ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am afraid this is no longer possible, according to [Region-specific block templates are not available in Drupal 8.](https://www.drupal.org/node/2011434)

> In Drupal 7 it was possible to specify separate block templates per
>   region, such as block--header.tpl.php and block--footer.php to output
>   different HTML for blocks placed in the header and footer regions. It
>   was also possible to adjust variables based on region in
>   hook_preprocess_block(). Both of these features have been removed.
>
> It is suggested you use standard CSS cascading selectors to style
>   blocks differently on different parts of the page.

Therefore, you have 2 options:

1) In your **page.html.twig** you add a parent/wrapper class or id

```
{% if page.sidebar %}
    <div class="my-sidebar">
       {{ page.sidebar}}
    </div>   
{% endif %}
```

Then in CSS use your parent/wrapper to style your blocks `.my-sidebar .block { border: solid red; }`

2) Individually create a **block--block--[id].html.twig** for each of your sidebar blocks and add `my-desired-class` here.

Comment: Excellent and Comprehensive answer, I appreciate you very much.

Comment: I'll have to look into this later when I get back home, but I see no reason why you can't use hook_preprocess_page or hook_preprocess_region, check if there is a block in the region and then add your classes in the preprocess function.

Comment: @Mark Conroy: Thank you for your attention, I'll be grateful if you post your solution.

Comment: @No Sssweat: Please edit your answer and add a space between `.my-sidebar` and `.block` It should be like: `.my-sidebar .block { border: solid red; }`, because `div's` with `block` class are descendants of `div's` with `my-sidebar` class , Thanks for everything again.

Comment: If 5 is OK, then 6 also must be ... i.e. I also endorse this answer ...